# window.innerWidth in JS doesn't equal to `width:100%` in css

Tags: javascript, css, ios9.1

I am creating a webpage on mobile, which will fit 100% width of the screen.

However, when I created some elements with JavaScript and set the width to `window.innerWidth`, they would be much wider than the static elements that set `width: 100%` in CSS. (on iPhone 6(s))

The `width: 100%` sets these elements to 375px, which I think is right, since the screen resolution is 1334 x 750. However the `window.innerWidth` is 488px, for whatever reason I really don't understand.

Is this a bug of the browser I am testing, or I miss something for retina screen?

By the way, I use `width:480px;max-width:100%` to set the static elements. The view-port meta is like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: 375 is right I'm not sure where the 488 is coming from ? Are you setting any elements to a hardcoded pixel value for the width? Are you using the correct viewport meta tag?

Comment: I set the width with `width:480px;max-width:100%`, so I think it should be alright

Answer (score 0):

Pixel ratio and sidebars can cause the innerwidth of window to be different depending on the device. If you need to check window width in javascript so your media queries match up. Use the window.matchmedia function.

JS

```
  if ( window.matchMedia('max-width:800').matches ){
        console.log('tablet mode');
  }
```